How to listen for addLiquidityETH transactions on Uniswap V2
I am trying to make a program that will listen for all the new tokens with liquidity on Uniswap V2 (Specifically Base chain but Ethereum works too)
I've run into many problems, most of which stem from addLiquidityETH not having an event. The first step would be a way to listen for transactions specifically on the Uniswap Router02. Any ideas?

Here is an example Python code how to listen to PairCreated events - you can do same in JavaScript
